# Как отправить событие в Windows EventLog Security с помощью Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, события, логирование

`ReportEvent(EventLog, EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS, 0, 4624, nil, 2, 0, @MyMsg, nil);`

Данная строчка записывает в лог Application

Как записать в лог Security?

Comment: [Only the Local Security Authority (Lsass.exe) has write permission for the Security log.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-logging-security)